# How to handle duplicate object in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to send values for particular field

I have found `Password` locaters value is same on [this](http://www.infibeam.com/) website.

How to handle same objects which have same `id`,`name`,`tagname` etc.?

Comment: Are you talking about login page at https://www.infibeam.com???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them like that :

- First one :

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='loginForm']/div/div/input[@id='password']")`

- Second one :

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='registration-form']/div/div/input[@id='password']")`

With that solution, you'll be sure to find the right element even if an other id=password is added before the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<WebElement>` to create a list of elements with *"same id,name,tagname"* and perform indexed operations as :

```
 List <WebElement> elements = driver.<your locator strategy>;
 for (int i = 0; i< elements.size(); i++) {
    elements.get(0).<perform your action>;
 }
```

Comment: I don't agree with that answer. Using indexed operations doesn't ensure you to find the correct element to be selected. If the page is modified and an other id="password" is added before, you won't understand why it doesn't work anymore.